# jQuery ajax calls only works in localhost

Tags: jquery, localhost

Hi all i have a simple jQuery ajax call in a site i'm currently developing. When I try to call it in "localhost" domain everything works fine in every browser, but when I host the site or load the site using my network name (in locahost) this jQuery call does not work. in firebug console, the ajax call just turn in to red and nothing returns. please advice me.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a code sample so it is a bit hard to say, but a likely possibility is the [Same Origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) for AJAX calls. That is, you can't normally send an AJAX request from a page hosted on Localhost to another domain.

Use a technology like [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to get around this.

If you show your code and the error message from the script I can probably give you a more precise diagnosis.